# Replacing rows in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix, adjacency-matrix

How can I replace any rows corresponding to all `0` entries in any matrix which say all entries in that row now `1/10` in matlab?

I have tried this so far however this doesn't work for all matrix sizes.

```
idxRow = all(A,2)==0
A(idxRow,:) = 0.1
```

Comment: Can you post an example for which it fails? Which sizes don't work?

Comment: `idxRow = all(A==0,2)`

Comment: Thankyou that seems to solve the problem. @LuisMendo